# Cheerio selection is empty/null

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

So I would appreciate some help on this one, tried a bit of everything.

```
let $ = cheerio.load("<html><table><tr><td>Example 1</td><td>Example 2</td></table>");
console.log($("td").text());
```

Gives this result (which is what I want):

```
// Example1Example2
```

However if I load a URL from a real web page, the result for the same selection is empty/null. This is the HTML for the page I load (not mine):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<div class="middle"><img src="./example.jpg" /></div>
<table class="bgColor centered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Example header 1</th>
<th>Example header 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Example 1</td>
<td>Example 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

And this is the code I run. There's no problem with the URL. I've tried different selectors but never got it right. Have been able to log some things but even though I use .text() it logs the whole html, with type, tag, etc... I'm probably missing something essential. But I left that out since I want the question to be simplified, and as far as I know I should be able to log the td's from this...
Leaves the console log with two empty rows:

```
let myFoo = function(theUrl) {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(theUrl, function (error, response, html) {
        if (error) {
            return reject(error);
        } else {
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            console.log($("td").text());
            resolve();
        }
    });
});
};
```

Edit:

When i console.log($); it gives this result. I'm not sure if it looks right? I'm new to node and cheerio.

```
{ [Function]
fn:
{ constructor: [Circular],
    _originalRoot:
    { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        attribs: {},
        children: [],
            next: null,
        prev: null,
        parent: null } },
load: [Function],
    html: [Function],
xml: [Function],
text: [Function],
parseHTML: [Function],
root: [Function],
contains: [Function],
_root:
{ type: 'root',
    name: 'root',
    attribs: {},
    children: [],
        next: null,
    prev: null,
    parent: null },
_options:
{ withDomLvl1: true,
    normalizeWhitespace: false,
    xmlMode: false,
    decodeEntities: true } }
```

And if I console.log($(html)); it gives this:

```
{ options:
{ withDomLvl1: true,
    normalizeWhitespace: false,
    xmlMode: false,
    decodeEntities: true } }
```

Comment: Try also doing console.log(html) to make sure it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks. I edited original post. 

I'm not really sure what I expect it to be, as I'm new to this... I took for granted this was what I got when logging the whole web page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant just the html and not $(html), console.log(html), to make sure it's actually the html code you want and has the td tags.

Comment: That one comes up blank. I really dont get that.
If I log the url and response I get result.

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: Nevermind, there actually was a problem with the url. A subpath had become missing somewhere in the process. Thanks for trouble shooting.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it's all working now. When everything seems like it should work it's time to start questioning our assumptions. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

I think this will solve the issue.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');

const response = axios.get('YOUR URL');
const $=cheerio.load(response.data);
console.log($("td").text());
```